# Robotium: how to use clickOnButton(<name>) for custom buttons

Tags: android, android-widget, robotium

I am new to Android robotium. I am having custom widgets(MyButton, MyTextView, MyCheckBox etc..,) which got inherited from native android widgets. How can i add a click event for my custom controls in a robotium script?

I tried using Solo.clickOnButton("Test Button") where the "Test Button" is an instance of MyButton, but i am not getting click event for the Button. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks,
-Ron..

Answer (score 0):

I suposse you create the MyButton using extend Button etc etc

Well to asign click action you should use the normal form. For expample

main.xml:

```
<com.Ron.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/custom_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your code you can acces to that button

```
 Button myButton  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.custom_button);
```

And then asign onClick action like you do with other normal button:

```
 myButton.setOnclickListener(new onclickListener ....
```

Other method to asing onClickAction to all views is use int the xml :

```
<com.Ron.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/custom_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="nameOfMethod"/>
```

And then in your code:

```
  public void nameOfMethod (View v){
    //code when click the view 
  }
```

(This works with all view, linearlayout, imageviews, bustom button .... all )

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. I am writing a test script for android using robotium which will automatically click Button. If i use Solo.clickOnButton(<name>) normally it will do the click action. But since i am using a custom button i am not able to do click using the function clickOnButton().

Comment: Sorry i never use Robotium :S Anyway try to create a instacen of your button Button myButton  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.custom_button); and use it in the robutium clickOnbutton method.